# How do I use functions inside map() in R, using the recommended way of passing arguments?

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I thought I understood how map() works but apparently I don't. I have a vector of filenames that correspond to real files in the working directory:

```
file_names <- c("filename1", "filename2", "filename3")
```

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data_frame(filename = file_names) %>%
  mutate(content = map(file_names, read_tsv))
```

But when I want to add arguments to read_tsv by using the recommended format `map(\\(x) f(x, arg1, arg2))`

```
data <- data_frame(filename = file_names) %>%
 mutate(content = map(\(file_names) read_tsv(file_names, skip = 1, col_names = FALSE)))
```

I get an error:

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ℹ In argument: `content = map(function(file_names) read_tsv(file_names, skip = 1, col_names = FALSE))`.
> Caused by error in `map()`:
> ! `.x` must be a vector, not a function.

I tried changing the file_names to .x and similar but I don't know how it's suppose to work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `?map` you can see that:

> map(.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)

Therefore you will still need `.x` (A list or atomic vector) in your `map` function, which would be your `file_names` vector. You should supply the function in the second argument (`.f`), which allows several formats for specifying it:

---

#### 1. A named function

This is not the recommended way.

> We now generally recommend against using ... to pass additional (constant) arguments to .f

```r
data_frame(filename = file_names) %>%
  mutate(content = map(file_names, read_tsv, skip = 1, col_names = FALSE))
```

---

#### 2. An anonymous function

You can define an anonymous function within `map`, with the format `function(argument) foo(argument)` or shorthand `\(argument) foo(argument)`, where `foo` is the actual function you are applying in `map`.

```r
data_frame(filename = file_names) %>%
  mutate(content = map(file_names, \(file_names) read_tsv(file_names, skip = 1, col_names = FALSE)))
```

---

#### 3. A formula

This is more of a "tidyverse" way of specifying functions, where you must combine `~` and `.x` to represent the first argument of the function.

```r
data_frame(filename = file_names) %>%
  mutate(content = map(file_names, ~read_tsv(.x, skip = 1, col_names = FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely missed that the vector wasn't piped in.
@EDIT: Yes, they don't recommend the named function way anymore. It's better with the anonymous function anyway since in R studio, you get the recommended suggestions for argument names for the function.